# Need assistance with removing or updating tiered pricing

Tags: tiered-pricing

I am looking to update the tiered pricing on our website, but cannot find any tiers in the "Product Information/Pricing" section of our products.

[image]

Is it possible that this was hardcoded in the past by a previous employee?

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if I am mistaken, and I will gladly delete this answer, but typically you just have to add a tier by clicking the `Add Tier` button:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

web, I actually discovered how to turn it off completely under the manage attribute sets submenu. Thank you.